# What's the maximum far plane of an o3d (webgl) projection?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, o3d

## Hi,

### I am using the following javascript...

```
  g_viewInfo.drawContext.projection = g_math.matrix4.perspective(
      g_math.degToRad(30), // 30 degree fov.
      g_client.width / g_client.height,
      1,                  // Near plane.
      9999);              // Far plane.
```

Can anyone tell me what the maximum far plane of an o3d (webgl) projection is?

I have tried using 5000 and 9999 but everything still seems to disappear at the same point. I have tried to locate this information in the SDK's current documentation.

Is there a reason for such a weak limitation?
Is it possible to hack the max value?

[image]

Comment: That's a... *far fetched* use of Borat... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played with the near plane in conjunction with the far plane and got the distancing problems sorted